# Applying coupon code in Uber Ride Request Api

Tags: android, uber-api

I'm integrating Uber Ride request api to my app . I just go through the documentation provided by the uber . Before requesting the uber ride whether the user can apply the coupon code  or referral code ??. Is there any provision for it in uber api .

Comment: refer this https://developer.uber.com/docs/ride-requests/tutorials/deep-links/promotions

Comment: Is this can be apply to deep link ?? . Im using ride request api

Answer (score 0):

The only way to apply promotion codes today is using a deep link. See the applyPromo deeplink here: https://developer.uber.com/docs/ride-requests/tutorials/deep-links/introduction

Comment: can you please tell me where to include the screenshots and video for getting PRIVILEGED Access??

Comment: Please add a link to the screenshots/video in the description field showing your apps use case working for your developer account.